# Javascript camera follow player (centered) on tile map

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I checked and found a good template to set-up tile maps via array  (at least good for people like that are still learning) though wanted to know if you can help me come up with idea for camera. I know that it has to be an object that updates it's coordinates every-time the player moves, however there is always something I am missing from all the tutorials I checked.

Here is the script (template) I have so far for the tile-map:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mapArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var grass = new Image();
var stone = new Image();

grass.src = 'grass.jpeg';
stone.src = 'sand.jpeg';

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

grass.onload = function() {
  stone.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
          context.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, 32, 32);
        }
        if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
          context.drawImage(stone, posX, posY, 32, 32);
        }
        posX += 32;
      }
      posY += 32;
      posX = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="400px" width="500px"></canvas>
```

Sorry for mixing html,css and javascript, though it should be simple enough. I am not using assets yet and would like to leave this one for later. Will set-up player with array maybe and css later on to change it's look on moving.

Can you please help with setting up a simple camera to center the player and follow it (if possible to render only the visible part of the map)?

Comment: Instead of moving the camera and the player, why dont you just move the tiles?

Comment: I guess that is another way to go. Any idea on how that can be done ? Any samples will be enough to get me going in that direction :)

Comment: Just add the x and y movement to `posX` and `posY`

Comment: The simplest thing is always the best for starters. Thanks, that will give me more than enough to play around with for awhile :)